# How to share a file between widget, service and app?

Tags: android, file, file-io, android-widget, intentservice

I'm writing an App and an accopmanying widget that needs data. This data is downloaded over the net. I'm planning to use a IntentService to do the downloading. This service will save the data as a file. This file is then used by both the App and widget.

How can I prevent the app and widget from reading the file while the service is writing to it?

And how can i prevent the service to write to the file while the app or the widget is reading the file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider extending `Application` and declaring a field for reading and writing permission:

```
public class APP extends Application {
    boolean motherMayI;

    ...
}
```

Then whenever you open a `FileInputStream` or a `FileOutputStream`,

```
...
if (motherMayI) {
    APP.motherMayI = false;
    FileInputStream input = context.openFileInput("some_file_name");

    //read your stuff

    input.close()
    APP.motherMayI = true;
}
...
```

Essentially, the field motherMayI must be true for someone to read or write the file, and its only false while its being read or written.

EDIT:

```
public FileInputStream getFileInputStream() {
    return context.openFileInput(file_name);
}
```

This would require an instance of `APP`.

Comment: Ok, this seems like a simple and good solution. But I dont know about the lifecycle for the Application-object. Is it available when no activitity is created and only widgets is created?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer to your question, but here's what I think: The widget reads a file, and therefore has to open a `FileInputStream`. This has to be done in Java, so the `Application` object is MOST LIKELY available. If not, just create a method in `APP` which returns a `FileInputStream`. See edit for clarification.